# How to show the same views with different data in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an app on iOS. In this app I have the following user flows:

- (Tab 1) All Pictures --> Individual Picture
- (Tab 3) User's Profile --> Edit Profile

1-In the Individual Picture screen there is a button with the author's name. Once the user touches this button, he is redirected to the author's profile screen.

2-In the User's Profile screen there is a thumbnail of the user's picture he uploaded. If a user touches one of the thumbnails he is redirected to the Individual Picture screen corresponding.

3-At last from the User Profile's screen there is a button to see the profile of the current user's followers. Once the user touches such a link, the screen reloads with the follower's profile.

My questions is how to handle the redirection. So far I used segues to connect the different views together (case 1 and 2) or I changed the data of the current view (case 3) but I have the feeling that it is a bit odd. Should I instead create a new UIViewController and push it to the navigation controller stack ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the new UIViewController is preferred if the User Interface is different for the views. Same ViewController can be used by creating a new instance at runtime and destroying it as the viewController pops.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I used the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier method of the storyboard to create a new instance of the viewController I wanted and then call pushViewController:newProfileViewController from the navigationController to display it. Then the user pops to the previous controller and with ARC, should I do anything special to destroy the former viewController or is it handled by default?